# How to get uid from a node on which is commented?

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks, comments

I'm using `hook_comment_view($comment)` and I'd like to confer the uid from the comment (`$comment->uid`) with the uid from the node on which is commented. I thought of `$node->uid`, but I don't know how I can define `$node`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you dpm() the $comment to see if the node is there?  I can't remember.

Comment: @MPD: Thanks to your `dpm()` hint, I found out that I could load the nid via `$comment`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could load the `$nid` via the comment and confer the uid's like this:

```
function mymodule_comment_view($comment) {
 $nid = $comment->nid;
 $node = node_load($nid);
 if ($comment->uid == $node->uid){
    //do something
 }
}
```

Comment: You can likely simplify this, too, by getting the $node->uid via a query.  Something like `$uid = db_query('SELECT n.uid FROM {node} n INNER JOIN {comment} c ON c.nid = n.nid WHERE c.cid = :cid', array(':cid' => $comment->cid))->fetchField();` would be a start.

Comment: @MPD: Is that a faster way? I'm no expert in this.

Comment: Full node loads can be expensive, especially if you have a lot of fields.  It is worth spending a little time with it, even if it is just to get used to doing db_queries for simple things.

Comment: @MPD: Indeed, running the code seems to go faster now. Thanks for your advice!