# How to hide a field in a comment in hook_comment_view programatically?

Tags: 7, hooks, comments

My comments have a field called 'Extra'. I'm trying to hide it when the user who's viewing the comment wrote it. This is my custom module:

```
function mymodule_comment_view($comment) {
  global $user;
  if ($comment->uid == $user->uid){
    unset ($comment->field_extra);
  }
}
```

Why isn't this working and what's the correct way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the same kind of functionality in the user.module function [user_comment_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_comment_view/7) I would expect your code to work.

If your function is really called `hook_comment_view` then it won't work though. Either this is just a typo, or rename your function to `MYMODULE_comment_view` where `MYMODULE` is the name of your custom module.

**Edit:** After a little discussion with MPD it turns out, that this actually works:

```
$comment->content['field_extra']['#access'] = FALSE;
```

Respect to MPD for explanations and an inside for why that could work and especially for why the other solution doesn't work!

This is the phrase from MPD that lead to the solution:

> If you read the source for [`comment_build_comment()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.module/function/comment_build_content/7), $comment->content[] has already been built up by the time the view hook gets invoked. So, messing with the field directly has no effect at this point.

Which means, that the field output has already been built and stored in `$comment->content`, which implies that this follows the same rules as in `hook_node_view()`. So accessing `$comment->content[FIELD_NAME]` should work.

Comment: Indeed, instead of "hook", I'm using "mymodule". I changed this in my question.

Comment: ah, ok, I was just looking at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/102730/how-to-get-uid-from-a-node-on-which-is-commented and figured from there that this was a typo ;) Then I'm baffled too about why it doesn't work. Can you add any information to the comment? Will it be displayed?

Answer (score 4):

[`hook_comment_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.api.php/function/hook_comment_view/7), along with most of the other entity view hooks, are typically used to *add* properties onto the entity object.

If you read the source for [`comment_build_comment()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.module/function/comment_build_content/7), `$comment->content[]` has already been built up by the time the view hook gets invoked.  So, messing with the field directly has no effect at this point.

You want to implement a [`template_process_comment()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.module/function/template_preprocess_comment/7) in your theme, or you can implement a module (which technically makes it an instance of [`hook_preprocess_comment()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7).

Implement this, and then [`dpm($variables)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/7) inside it.  Figure out what you don't want, and then [`unset()`](http://www.php.net/unset) it.  If the variable is printed directly from the [comments template](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.tpl.php/7), this is is directly in `$variables`.  If it is in the content section, then unset the proper key in `$variables['content']`, which is a render tree.

Comment: So then it should be possible to do `$comment->field_extra = '';` as it is done in [user_comment_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_comment_view/7)?

Comment: @berliner Adding your own property, yes, but I am not sure if altering a true field this way is really safe. Mainly I am not sure how field caching comes into play.  Also, an empty field is also normally the empty array.

Comment: ok, then your's is the way to go I guess. Thanks for explaining

Comment: @berliner I filled out my explanation a bit.  I had to do some field-level shenanigans on a project a few weeks ago, and ran into some of the same issues.

Comment: Shouldn't it be possible then to do `$comment->content['field_extra']['#access'] = FALSE`? That's the way I would do it in a `hook_node_view()`.

Comment: @berliner: I tried `$comment->field_extra['#access'] = FALSE` and that didn't work, but I forgot the `content`. I tried it again with your version and **it works**! I'll mark your answer after you've updated it. Thanks!